# missing python language when i created azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm new for azure. i just tried to create azure function for python script, but under language list, python language is missing.

[image]

Comment: Did you create a function app based on Windows OS? python need based on Linux.

Comment: Any process , could you create the function now?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need create the Linux OS Function, for now the Python is not support on Windows OS. So when you create the Function you should choose the Linux OS then you will be able to choose the Python stack.

[image]

Secondly, after you create the function, for now in-portal file editing this feature is disabled, You could check this issue:[In-portal editing will be disabled for Python Functions](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/157). So you have to use the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python) or [VS Code extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/functions-extension/getting-started). Then upload the local function to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`VS CODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python) for the same . [`Visual Studio 2017/2019`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) only supports C#.

You can install the package for VS CODE WITH

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```